# How do I convert a string to a JSONObject in kotlin from openweather response?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, openweathermap

I would like some help converting an openweather response to a JSONObject right now I am able to get the response using this class.

```
import java.net.URL

class ConexionClima {

public fun conseguirRespuestaDeAPI(lat: Double, lon: Double): String ?{

    val apiKey: String = "99ccac116e6924f62f669458a754299c"
    var respuesta: String?
    val urlStr = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=2.0&lon=1.0&appid=99ccac116e6924f62f669458a754299c"

    try{
        respuesta = URL(urlStr).readText(Charsets.UTF_8)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        respuesta = null
    }
    return respuesta
  }


}
```

But when I try to convert it using this function

```
fun resolverPrimerProblema(latitud: Double, longitud: Double): String{
    val cc = ConexionClima()
    val datos : String? = cc.conseguirRespuestaDeAPI(latitud, longitud)
    if (datos != null) {
        val datosJson = JSONObject(datos)
    }

    return("")
}
```

It just says that "datosJson" is set to null even though the string used is not null and is the response from openWeather. I know this from debugging.

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong or what the correct way of doing this is?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: What happens when there’s an exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably because you are getting an exception and therefore your variable `respuesta` is returning as null

This is also probably happening because you are executing a network call on the main thread and therefore getting this exception:

> NetworkOnMainThreadException

This is why i would recommend using [Volley](https://github.com/google/volley) or [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) etc, but if you are keen on trying this, execute your code on a different thread by doing something like:

```
  Thread {
     resolverPrimerProblema(latValue, longValue)
  }.start()
```

Comment: Yep running a network call on main thread was the issue, thank you very much!

Comment: @RubénVillalpandoBremont glad i could help